# How to test a program that uses Boost.MPI with Boost.Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, mpi

I would like to unit-test with `Boost.Test` a parallel program that uses `Boost.MPI`. The official documentation of these libraries don't provide instructions on how to do this (or I could not find them). The problem is that MPI code needs initialisation and finalisation done *only once* which `Boost.MPI` encapsulates in the `environment` (and to some extent in the `communicator`) objects, RAII style. So a `Boost.MPI` program would normally look like this:

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
  boost::mpi::communicator world{};
  
  // ... parallel code here ...
}
```

However, `Boost.Test` supplies its own `main()` function behind the scenes. This I can override by defining `#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN` and then writing the `main()` myself, along the lines sketched above.

But then the problems begin. How to tell `Boost.Test` to run the test cases under MPI? Should they be defined as `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(...)` macros as usual or is there another way? And how can one "pass" the `communicator` object (`world`) to the test cases? Should it be set up in a global fixture? If yes, then how do global fixtures work together with a user-supplied `main`?

I have experimented a lot, Googled even more, and found nothing usable. Is there anyone out there who knows how to use these two Boost libraries together? If yes, then a *working* example would be much appreciated. Thanks.

*EDIT* SebastianH-s suggestion quickly slapped together:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE mpitest
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN

#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bmpi = boost::mpi;

// Fixture
struct Fix {
    Fix(): env{}, world{} {}
    bmpi::environment env;
    bmpi::communicator world;
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(check_mpi, Fix) {
    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::cout << "MPI thread level: " <<
        bmpi::environment::thread_level() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size()
            << "." << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // This runs the test cases.
    int retval = boost::unit_test::unit_test_main([](){ return true; }, argc, argv );
}
```

Compiles with `g++ 9.3` and `Boost` 1.71 under Ubuntu. But when I run it:

```
Running 1 test case...
*** The MPI_Comm_set_errhandler() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
```

See, that's the problem: MPI is not correctly initialised.

Comment: Did you think about a test fixture? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/case.html

Comment: @SebastianH How would you get `argc` and `argv` into the fixture to initialise `boost::mpi::environment` ? I put together quickly something based on your suggestion (see edit in the question), it won't run as written. Concrete improvements welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two solutions.

**Solution 1: Use global configuration**

This is quite simple and elegant. The key is to initialise MPI
in a [Boost.Test global configuration](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_global_configuration.html) class (which is not the same as a [global fixture](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/global.html)).

Code:

```
#include "boost/mpi/environment.hpp"
#include "boost/mpi/communicator.hpp"
namespace bmpi = boost::mpi;

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE mpitest
#include "boost/test/unit_test.hpp"
namespace bt = boost::unit_test;

#include <iostream>

struct GlobalConfig {
    GlobalConfig():
    env(
        bt::framework::master_test_suite().argc, 
        bt::framework::master_test_suite().argv,
        bmpi::threading::multiple)
    { }
    bmpi::environment env;
};

BOOST_TEST_GLOBAL_CONFIGURATION(GlobalConfig);
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(mpitest);

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(check_mpi) {
    bmpi::communicator world;   // refers to global MPI_COMM_WORLD instance
    BOOST_CHECK(world.size() > 1);
    
    auto myrank = world.rank();
    if (myrank == 0) {
        std::cout << "MPI thread level: " << bmpi::environment::thread_level() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "I am process " << myrank << " of " << world.size() << std::endl;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

**Solution 2: Build the test suite manually**

This is more complicated because you have to provide a `main()` function,
and put together the test suite manually.

Code:

```
#include "boost/mpi/environment.hpp"
#include "boost/mpi/communicator.hpp"
namespace bmpi = boost::mpi;

#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE mpitest
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include "boost/test/unit_test.hpp"
namespace bt = boost::unit_test;

#include <iostream>

// This is a test case which we will add manually to the test suite.
// see `register_tests()`
void check_mpi() {
    bmpi::communicator world;   // refers to global MPI_COMM_WORLD instance
    BOOST_CHECK(world.size() > 1);
    
    auto myrank = world.rank();
    if (myrank == 0) {
        std::cout << "MPI thread level: " << bmpi::environment::thread_level() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "I am process " << myrank << " of " << world.size() << std::endl;
}

// Put together a test suite manually.
void register_tests() {
    bt::test_suite* ts = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("mpitest");

    // Add a test case
    ts->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &check_mpi ));
    // ... add more test cases ...

    // Add the test suite to the "master" test suite
    // which is always provided by the Boost.Test framework
    bt::framework::master_test_suite().add(ts);
}

// == MAIN ==

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bmpi::environment env(argc, argv, bmpi::threading::multiple);
    bmpi::communicator world;

    register_tests();

    // Run the master test suite.
    // The lambda first argument has to be used if BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK is set
    int retval = bt::unit_test_main([](){ return true; }, argc, argv );
    return retval;
}
```

Save either program as `mpitest.cc`, compile (under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with `g++ 9.3` and `Boost 1.71`) as follows:

```
mpicxx -std=c++17  mpitest.cc -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK \
   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_unit_test_framework \
   -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization  -o mpitest
```

Run as follows:

`mpirun -np 2 ./mpitest`

Expected output:

```
Running 1 test case...
Running 1 test case...
I am process 1 of 2
MPI thread level: multiple
I am process 0 of 2

*** No errors detected
*** No errors detected
```